# What is the fourth dimension of a Tesseract?

Tags: geometry, visualization

Is the fourth dimension of the [Tesseract](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tesseract) time? Is that why it is represented as a moving 3D structure on Wikipedia? I am asking because I have trouble understanding what it is.

Comment: First and foremost, time is not **the** fourth dimension. Time is one of the dimensions that makes up our 4-dimensional space time. Not every context that speaks about four dimensions includes time. In the case of the tesseract, we think about four *spacial* dimensions, something which (as far as we know) does not exist in our universe.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1wAaI_6b9JE

Comment: @M.Winter Four _spatial_ dimensions??? Can we have three co-planer dimensions, or two singular dimensions? We gotto think Tesseract in exact same way. Btw which theory says "time is not fourth dimension" as you mentioned? Spacetime is widely received concept & been proved and we all know space is three dimension.

Comment: @Atul I don't understand most of your comment. For the last part: if you read my comment carefully you see that I state that time is indeed one of the four dimensions of spacetime. Beyond that, my comment does not address physical reality.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It isn't time. The tesseract is an object in 4 (or higher) space dimensions. However, since we live in 3 dimensions, it is not possible for us to see a tesseract in all its glory. What we can see is the projection of a tesseract on a 3d plane. Now, depending on which plane is chosen for the projection, the tesseract looks different.

The diagram on Wiki is trying to give you the best possible "view" of the tesseract by rotating the plane on which the projection is being done, thereby allowing you to see all possible projections of the tesseract.

In fact, the text below the picture clearly states this

> A 3D projection of an 8-cell performing a simple rotation about a plane which bisects the figure from front-left to back-right and top to bottom

EDIT: Based on comments below, I'm adding the following notes -

Firstly, a tesseract is a mathematical construct. It is a description of what a higher dimensional object would look like if such higher dimensions existed. Secondly, how do you conclude that you do not have such objects popping out of the 4th dimension, if it existed? You must remember that the world that you and I can see need not be the entire story. It may be true that higher dimensions exist but we can't access it. That is a totally logical possibility.

For instance, imagine an ant walking on a piece of paper. As far as the ant is concerned, it knows only of the 2 dimensions of the paper. Does that mean that the 3rd dimension that it cannot see doesn't exist? No! It simply means that the ant can only see and make sense of objects living on the paper or projections of three-dimensional objects on that paper. If the ant were smart enough, by studying the properties of the projected objects, it could infer the existence of the 3rd dimension without ever having seen it. The same logic applies to us. We will never be able to directly see the 4th dimension, but imprints of its existence might be present in the 3 dimensions that we can see. By properly understanding these, we can make progress. PS - String theorists believe that the world has 9 dimensions (+1 time dimension).

Comment: Alright, so what is the 4th dimension then? How it exist in this world if we don't see it? We don't have random objects popping out of the 4th dimension and projecting on our world.
I don't understand what this 4th dimension means/represents.

Comment: @ConradC **it is nothing.** A 4-D object doesn't exist any more than a 2-D one or a matrix or an integral or a number do. It's just a math thingy to help us do some stuff.

Comment: @Ruslan - Commends deleted, answer edited.

Comment: @AndréNeves If it's nothing, then what exists in this dimension?

Comment: @ConradC nothing. This dimension doesn't exist.

Comment: @AndréNeves - What do you mean "This dimension doesn't exist".

Comment: That trying to find ways to accomodate a fourth dimension in the usual organoleptic perception of space is fruitless, and it's all too common. These days I saw some content on Quora teaching people how to "visualize five more dimensions" -- a complete waste of time. People entertaining this exercise are often laypeople trying to find practical, day-to-day meaning in math and physics talk of tesseracts, 11-dimensions (superstrings) and such. They're wasting their time. Such concepts have their very important uses, but it's not what they're looking for.

Answer (score 1):

Simply, imagine some polystyrene balls (acting as points). Put one down. This is 0 dimensions. It cannot go anywhere. It is stationary. It has no properties.

Then, add $x$ balls next to it.It is now a line, or mathematically/physically, 1 dimension. You can travel forwards or backwards on it.

In a perpendicular fashion, add more balls until it creates a square. This "pen" / "cage" is two dimensional. you can go left or right. Also, it carries the property of 1D ; letting you go backwards or forwards (That is why a square is called a '2D Shape').

IMAGINE a cube. It has many layers of squares on it. $x$ layers in fact. You are inside it. You can do anything you would normally do. Go up or down. But also, you are able to do anything a 2D person could do. So in 3D, you can go LEFT or RIGHT or FORWARDS or BACKWARDS. That is an example of YOU.

What about the fourth dimension? So, if you haven't noticed, the $d$ dimension equivalent of a cube would have $d$ edges coming off each of its vertices. e. g. A square has two edges coming off it at a vertice. Three for a cube. One for a line. And none for a point.

[image: What I mean.]

Answer (score 0):

No, it's not time. Prahar is correct that it's basically the best way we can visualise it as 3D beings.

It's hard to describe in words, but if you're interested I would recommend reading Flatland: A Romance in Many Dimensions. It's a short story about a square trying to understand the 3D world, but it's easy to extrapolate the ideas to 3D and 4D (http://www.gutenberg.org/files/201/201-h/201-h.htm)

Using the analogy of 2D to 3D, imagine a being living on a piece of paper: Their world is 2D. How would this being see a sphere? They would see it as a series of 2D splices as it travels through the sheet of paper.

When we look at a Tesseract, we are basically doing the same thing: we can only see it as a series of 3D images changing with time, hence why it is animated.

Comment: For example, imagine the world of a cartoon character. It's two dimensional. [Imagine a cartoon character popping into our 3D universe](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Treehouse_of_Horror_VI#Homer3_.28Homer_Cubed.29). What would he think?

Comment: you mentioned moving in time,as a way of understanding its geometry, and you said the 4th dimension is not time. so how is it not? and why not? and if not so what is the Tesseract's 4th dimension? is it some physical dimension?